# Failed to load IDA PLW plugin

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

I am trying to install mIDA plugin for IDA.

I found a compiled PLW file here: https://github.com/sourceincite/tools/tree/master/pymsrpc/mIDA , downloaded it and saved it to `C:\Program Files\IDA 7.0\plugins`.
For some reason, I don't see the plugin in IDA plugins (EDIT->PLUGINS).

According to the installation instructions, I just need to copy the PLW file to the plugins directory, but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions or ideas what can I do differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IDA 7.0 is a 64-bit program and cannot load 32-bit PLW files. The plug-in needs to be ported and recompiled for the new API:

https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/news/7_0/docs/api70_porting_guide/